# Attempting to create a toolbar with notebook tabs, unable to properly integrate functions

Tags: functions, notebooks, user-interface

I recently learned that all the default Mathematica palettes were actually created in mathematica, and i have been trying to make something similar myself. And since learning that the DockedCell option had a toolbar-like effect, i have been trying to create a toolbar to cut down on screen space while retaining the utility of the palettes. So far i have created;

[image: ![enter image description here]

The purpose of this question, is i would like to integrate tabs, since i often have multiple notebooks open to edit portions of code from my main projects without interfering with the main notebook. Tabs would make this much easier. The only information i have about creating a tabbed notebook comes from;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778774/how-to-create-tabbed-mathematica-notebooks

Where there was code given that creates notebook tabs exactly as i had in mind. The code is fairly complicated however, and i was unable to integrate it with my current code for the toolbar. My current code intentionally makes no use of dynamic variables or functions.

```
CreateWindow[DockedCells ->{Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[ Grid[{Append[ PasteButton[RawBoxes[#], 
ImageSize -> {80, 40}, Appearance -> "FramedPalette"] & /@ { (lengthy contents of buttons)}, 

Item[ActionMenu["Style", {"Title" :>FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "Style", "Title"],

"Subtitle" :>FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "Style", "Subtitle"],
(action menu list item, more can be inserted)
}], Alignment -> Right]],
{

Button["Move Back", SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], Previous, Cell],
Appearance -> "Palette"],
(buttons, more can be inserted)
}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]]], "DockedCell", Background -> LightGray],

Cell[BoxData[
ToBoxes[Grid[{PasteButton[RawBoxes[#], ImageSize -> {15, 15}, 
      Appearance -> "FramedPalette"] & /@
    {(special characters in last row)}
   }]]], "DockedCell", Background -> White]}]
```

Anything in parenthesis should be deleted or replaced if you would like to experiment with this code for yourself. I only added one of each button in this example to reduce length, the code for each button is identical and can be copy-pasted to create more.

The code given in the above referenced post is what i would like to integrate, which has proven difficult. My attempts involve mostly trying to get a portion of the given code to act as a cell in a new row above the 2 i currently have, and turning the whole block of code into a single function as is done in the referenced post. i did not post any of the code referenced in the post, or my complete code, because it was too long.

This question is a bit of a longshot, and rather difficult. Just part of my aspiration to make something cool as someone who has known the Mathematica language for less than 3 months. My last question i posted was a massive help, so here i am again. If i can be more specific about anything, please let me know!

Kind regards,
Will